# IE setting "Access data sources across domains" help understanding

Tags: internet-explorer, office-js

Windows 7 Internet Explorer setting has Access data sources across domains setting disabled. We run a officejs app using angular to get data from a web api. The object is to migrate our Windows 7 to Windows 10 with the same security settings. However when the app runs under Windows 10, pre-flight which cors requires does not start (even in Fiddler no data is returned from request).

I would like specifics on what this setting actually is doing between the two environments. On Windows 7, it doesn't affect the application at all set or not set. But on Windows 10, only works when this setting is enabled.

Answer (score 0):

The Access data sources across domains policy setting allows you to manage whether Internet Explorer can access data from another security zone using the Microsoft XML Parser (MSXML) or ActiveX Data Objects (ADO).

If you enable this policy setting, users can load a page in the zone that uses MSXML or ADO to access data from another site in the zone. If you select Prompt in the drop-down box, users are queried to choose whether to allow a page to be loaded in the zone that uses MSXML or ADO to access data from another site in the zone.

If you disable this policy setting, users cannot load a page in the zone that uses MSXML or ADO to access data from another site in the zone.

If you do not configure this policy setting, users are queried to choose whether to allow a page to be loaded in the zone that uses MSXML or ADO to access data from another site in the zone.

This policy supported on: At least Internet Explorer 6.0 in Windows XP with Service Pack 2 or Windows Server 2003 with Service Pack 1. Please check the IE browser version.

Comment: HI Zhi, it's interesting to know what you think it means. What does this have to do with the behavior described above? The angular call to web api doesn't do pre-flight on win10, but it's fine on win7.

Comment: Please check the IE browser version they are using? I was thinking perhaps the issue is related that they are using a different version.  Besides, I think you could also try to use F12 developer tools or Fiddler to check the http request, and compare them.

Comment: Sure, more info: we are using ie 11 in both cases. When running fiddler on the win10 machine, it doesn't even try to go there. Pre-flight does not occur. On the server, CORS is set to allow any/all * in the web.config.